# Refused UK visitor visa

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals, russian-citizens

I applied on the 11th October for a visitor visa to the UK. Today, my passport was returned and the visa refused.

I'm a Russian national, living in Greece for the last 18 years, have a permanent residence card, own my home. On my application, I provided:

- 6 months payslips
- Employer statement that I work there for 2 years, plus the monthly income
- Tax Status of 2015 (showing my house, taxes, and annual income for 2015)
- Personal statement of mine that I get paid in cash from my job (which is allowed in Greece)
- Bank statement of my bank balance (I have stated that this is my savings account and didn't provide bank statements covering 6 months for that reason).
- Phone bill showing my property and in my name.
- Permament residence card copy.
- Invitation by my girlfriend stating I will stay for 4 days at a hotel

I have been refused with the following reason:

> As evidence of your own funds and financial circumstances you have submitted a bank account in your own name which shows a closing balance of 1,040 Euro. However, whilst I have considered the documents submitted I'm not satisfied that you have sufficiently demonstrated the origin of the funds."
>
> I'm not satisfied that you have sufficiently demonstrated your personal circumstances and funds or that you can be relied upon to meet the conditions of visit entry clearance. I'm not satisfied that you intend to leave the UK at the end of your visit. I am not satisfied that you have sufficient funds available to cover your costs whilst in the UK without working or using public funds.

Please note I have applied only to stay for 4 days as my girlfriend moved to Sheffield to study at the university. I have stated that my maximum visit would be 4 days per month due to work, house duties and having a pet.

I don't know how to move forward from now on or what to show as evidence, as if I get my 6 months bank statements there are only small deposits by me and internet purchases. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

[image]